# Braintree Drop-In UI requires reload to work properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I'm just getting started with the Braintree drop-in UI. Client side is javascript, server side is ruby on rails.

My system is very simple right now. The user is given a list of invoices that pertain to them. When the invoices have not yet been paid, they can click 'pay' and be taken to a new page that includes the Braintree Drop-In UI. My issue is this: When the user is taken to the 'pay' page, the drop-in UI does not appear. If the user reloads the page, the drop-in UI appears.

Why?

Here's some relevant code. It's pretty vanilla and not done yet - just roughed in.

From invoices/index.html.erb

```
<td>
  <% if invoice.paid %>
    <%= 'Paid' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Pay', payment_path(invoice.id) %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

From payments_controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_action :set_invoice, only: [:pay, :checkout]

  def pay
      Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox
      Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = 'merchant id'
      Braintree::Configuration.public_key = 'public key'
      Braintree::Configuration.private_key = 'private key'
      gon.client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate()
  end

    def checkout
        nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
        result = Braintree::Transaction.sale :amount => @invoice.amount, :payment_method_nonce => "nonce-from-the-client"
        if result.success?
            message='Payment processed successfully. Thank you!'
            @invoice.paid=true
            @invoice.save
        else
            message='Unable to process payment. Reason = ' + result.message
        end
        redirect_to invoices_path, notice: message
    end

    private
        def set_invoice
            @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

pay.html.erb:

```
<h1>Payments</h1>

<div>
    <p>Invoice #: <%= @invoice.id %></p>
    <p>Date: <%= @invoice.date %> </p>
    <p>Description: <%= @invoice.description %> </p>
    <p>Amount: <%= @invoice.amount %> </p>
</div>

<div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <h2 class="mbs">New Transaction</h2>
  <%= form_tag payments_checkout_path do%>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'id', @invoice.id %>
      <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
      <div id="dropin"></div>
      <%=submit_tag "Pay #{@invoice.amount}$", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

and layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <title>Actionable Software</title>
              <%= include_gon %>
              <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
              <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
              <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
              <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>


      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

        <div class='container'>
            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
            <% end %>

            <%= yield %>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess the script that populates that element isn't written in a way that works with Turbolinks.

Try [opting that page or section out of turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks).  Or just disable it completely and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue in my app.. change on your index page

```
<%= link_to 'Pay', payment_path(invoice.id) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Pay', payment_path(invoice.id), data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```

This should force the pay page to load completeley when you click through.